# ¿Por qué la funcion esta encerrada entre comillas?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Encontre el siguiente codigo en internet, se trata de dos funciones en las cuales: la primera esta siendo asignada a una variable dentro de ella misma, supongo que se trata de recursividad. Mientras tanto, en la segunda simplemente se hace una llamada a la primera.

Lo que me parece curioso es que en ambas invocaciones a la funcion esta encerrada entre comillas. Soy nuevo con esto de JavaScript y nunca habia visto algo parecido ¿Por qué sucede esto? ¿Hay alguna manera de invocarla sin comillas? Adjunto codigo.

```
function animate(d) {
    if (d>eol) {
      map.panTo(endLocation.latlng);
      marker.setPosition(endLocation.latlng);
      return;
    }
    var p = polyline.GetPointAtDistance(d);
    map.panTo(p);
    marker.setPosition(p);
    updatePoly(d);
    timerHandle = setTimeout("animate("+(d+step)+")", tick);
  }

  function startAnimation() {
    eol=polyline.Distance();
    map.setCenter(polyline.getPath().getAt(0));
    poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline({path: [polyline.getPath().getAt(0)], strokeColor:"#0000FF", strokeWeight:10});
    setTimeout("animate(50)",2000);  // Tiempo inicial para que se muestre el mapa
  }
```

Comment: Cuando se usan las comillas suele ser para escribir dentro un texto por eso tiene un + donde se concatena con un código

Comment: Porque así lo establece [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), la cual te invito a leer más a menudo. En todo caso, el uso de una expresión de tipo `string` no es recomendado, tal como no lo es el uso del método [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setTimeout() puede hacer uso de [**eval()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/eval#Utilice_funciones_en_lugar_de_evaluar_fragmentos_de_c%C3%B3digo) para ejecutar las instrucciones proporcionadas, pero es una mala práctica y se menciona en la documentación.

Si envías como parámetro la función con paréntesis (`animate(50)`) se va a ejecutar inmediatamente, sin aplicar el tiempo de espera, supongo que por eso la encerraron entre comillas, pero hay otras alternativas:

```js
function log(parametro) {
    console.log(parametro);
}
// Usando eval: mala práctica
setTimeout("log('Después de timeout');", 300);
// Sin encerrar entre comillas se ejecuta inmediatamente
setTimeout(log('No hay timeout'), 3000);

// Buenas prácticas 1: Agregar los parámetros al final
setTimeout(log, 500, 'Esta es la forma correcta de ejecutar');
// Buenas prácticas 2: Usar función anónima
setTimeout(() => {
    log('También es correcto usar una función anónima');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Wow amigo, eres el mejor, muchas gracias por sacarme la duda. Esto me pasa por no leer la documentacion :(